# Php / Codeigniter File Download

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I'm trying to download file in php. I used both codeigniter download helper and pure php code readfile. I can get the contents of file in browser's Network but I can not download it.

When I tried the readfile function in an independent php file it worked.

Here is my code block for dowload file.

```
// codeigniter
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents(base_url("/images/logo.png"));
force_download($decodedFileInfo->fileName, $data);

// php readfile
$file = "./images/logo.png"; //. $decodedFileInfo->fileName;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}else{
    var_dump("hst");die;
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: `file_get_contents(base_url(...))` is going to do an http request to your own server. WHY? WHy can't you just bypass the http layer entirely and fetch it directly from the file system? That's FAR more efficient than forcing a full http roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

Try Saving the file name and image name in variables and echo them on the screen.
I tested this functions works perfectly:

```
$this->load->dbutil();

//Calling a store procedure 
$sp ="exec secondProc '5 Aug 2013'";
$query = $sqlsrvr->query($sp);//->result();
$jawad =  $query->result_array();

//pass it to db utility function
$new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);

//Downloading the file
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('csv_file.csv', $new_report);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");
```